# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - Convert a varchar to money with a $ sign & 2 decimals

Tags: sql-server, string, sum

A table of financials has been provided to me with the following datatypes:

```
billed varchar 9
allowed varchar 9
paid varchar 7
```

with the following columns and values:

```
billed = 2555    allowed  = 1051   paid = 951
```

I want to convert the varchar values (the whole column) to money or to some format where I'll have a $ sign and the number will have 2 decimal points instead of rounding up. I need the SUM to remain because I'm adding up values throughout the columns based on the date.

My Expected Results are:

```
BILLED
$2,554.67

ALLOWED         
$1,050.75

PAID
$950.75
```

I have code that I've used, but I can't seem to format it correctly to be viewable in the post.`

Comment: ``` This is the code I tried to use: 
SELECT LEFT([date],6), ('$' + CONVERT(varchar(9), CAST(SUM([billed]) AS MONEY),1)) AS BILLED, 
        `('$' + CONVERT(varchar(9), CAST(SUM([allowed]) AS MONEY),1)) AS ALLOWED,`
        `('$' + CONVERT(varchar(7), CAST(SUM([paid]) AS MONEY),1)) AS PAID`
        `FROM dbo.[payments]`
        `GROUP BY LEFT([date],6)`
        `ORDER BY 1;`
```

Comment: [edit] any additional into directly into your question.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 17.9. You've given the version of SQL Server Management Studio that you're running. Execute `select @@version` to get the SQL Server version. Also, this is not something you should be doing in your query - save formatting like this for the application/report tier. But you also have a problem with your data - your numbers shouldn't be stored as text, and it's impossible to get the results you've asked for from the source data provided - you can't "unround" 2555 to 2554.67

Comment: @alroc They are stored as text because of the way the file was provided to me (.txt) I don't have permissions/access to change the datatype from the raw file, so I have to convert the varchar dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the values as `numeric`, do math with a function like `sum`, format as `money` and concatenate the **$** symbol at the beginning.

**Simplified example doing conversion:**

```
select ('$' + FORMAT(CONVERT(MONEY, cast([allowed] as numeric(38,2))), '###,###.####')) as AllowedConversionExample 
from dbo.payments
```

**Simplified example with math using sum()**

```
select
    '$' + FORMAT(CONVERT(MONEY, sum(cast(V.Val as numeric(38,2)))), '###,###.####')
from (
select cast('1050.75' as varchar(9)) Val
union select cast('950.75' as varchar(9)) 
) V
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @vvv4d. This table contains over 4m rows, so I would have to have a code where I don't have to call out each dollar amount. Is there a way for me to apply a code to all of the values in the table?

Comment: @BrandesMoore use the formula `'$' + FORMAT(CONVERT(MONEY, cast(V.Val as numeric(38,2))), '###,###.####')` and change **V.Val** to one of the different column names on 4m row table that you want to convert.

Comment: @vvv4d I'm note understanding what you're trying to convey. Your suggested code doesn't account for a table name and I'm getting additional errors. I only provided the dollar values to show what my original data was and what I'm expecting. For ex.,
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM"
"Incorrect syntax near 'V'"

Comment: @BrandesMoore  `select ('$' + FORMAT(CONVERT(MONEY, cast([allowed] as numeric(38,2))), '###,###.####')) as AllowedConversionExample from dbo.payments`

Comment: I wished that worked. Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Here's what I've entered:

SELECT LEFT([date],6), '$' + FORMAT(CONVERT(MONEY, SUM(CAST([Paid Amount]) as numeric (38,2))), '###,###.####') FROM dbo.[payments]
GROUP BY LEFT([date],6)
ORDER BY 1;

Comment: The 'date' column is a stand alone column that shouldn't be concatenated to another column. There's still a syntax error near the FROM statement when I replace the ',' with a '+'. The only part that should be concatenated is the '$' with the value in the specified row so that the values will look like this: $256.50.